# getting ID of <li> in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the ID of a `<li>` item.

The item is as follows:

```
echo ($y<$sites-1)?"<li id='" . $sit[0] ."'>":"<li id='$sit[0]' class=\"last\">";
echo "<a href=\"javascript:selectedSite();\" onClick=\"javascript:submit(1);\" onMouseOver=\"mouseAction(1)\" onMouseOut=\"mouseAction(0)\">" . $sit[1] . "</a></li>";
```

and this is my function:

```
function selectedSite()
{
    alert(/*I want the ID goes here*/);
}
```

Comment: You eneraly get more power / flexibility by setting the event handlers in Javascript instead of inline in the HTML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have to do it inline, the following will work for you:

```
echo "<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"selectedSite(this);submit(1);\" ...
```

```
function selectedSite(item)
{
    alert(item.parentNode.id);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not correct. The code will be invoked globally (like passing a string to `setTimeout`) so `this` won't be a reference to the element clicked.

Comment: Then you must have changed something. Passing `this` only works from inline event handlers like `onclick`.

Comment: @ЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖ: The sample you provided doesn't give the ID, it points to the element itself. But if you put it just as Tim, `alert(item.parentNode.id);` will definitely work.

Comment: @sikas: The point of the sample was that it points to the `window`. If you find that it points to the element, then it must be a browser compatibility issue. I'm testing in `Chrome`. Where are you testing? In [this updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/F2C2a/1/) it catches the error thrown. Does it do the same for you?

Comment: @TimCooper: How about you? Which browser are you using to test?

Comment: Also tested in Firefox, and it fails there too.

Comment: @ЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖ:  I'm seeing the results you mentioned.  I'll update my answer accordingly.  Strange I wasn't experiencing it before.  Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @ЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖ: I'm testing in chrome ... try this, it is working fine with me ( http://jsfiddle.net/mKmN7/ ) just check the `href` attribute and the `onClick` ... this way it will work on Chrome.